# FromDigits of list of list

Tags: list-manipulation

Instead of

```
FromDigits[{2, 1, 1}, 2]
```

with output `11`, I want to insert a whole list of lists instead of `{2,1,1}`.

So if
`lis = {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}`
I want as output: `{11, 7, 4}` but `FromDigits[lis, 2]` does not work. How can I do it?

Comment: FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ lis is another way.

Answer (score 8):

The list of lists is read column-wise, so you need to transpose `lis`:

```
FromDigits[Transpose[lis], 2]
```

> {11, 7, 4}

If the list is ragged then `FromDigits[Transpose[PadRight[lis]], 2]`

Comment: This will not work though if `lis` is a ragged list...